# SQL query for retrieving multiple emails in one record

Tags: sql, row

I have these tables

> ```
> | idEmail   | idPerson | email     |  
> |   213     |     1    |abc@abc.com|
> |   214     |     2    |def@abc.com|
> |   215     |     2    |fed@abc.com|
>
> | idPerson   | name | lastName     | 
> |     1      | Joe  |    Black     | 
> |     2      | Will |    Smith     |
> ```

I would like to retrieve one record for each person showing all mails adresses like this:

> ```
> | Name   | lastName | email 1   |  email 2  | 
> | Joe    |  Black   |abc@abc.com|           |
> | Will   |  Smith   |def@abc.com|fed@abc.com|
> ```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Right now Access 2016, might use Mysql aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `JOIN` then do condition aggregate function.

```
SELECT  Name,
        lastName,
        MAX(CASE WHEN t1.idPerson = 1 then email end) 'email 1',      
        MAX(CASE WHEN t1.idPerson = 2 then email end) 'email 2'
FROM t1 JOIN t2 on t1.idPerson = t2.idPerson 
group by  Name,lastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into the PIVOT statement as well or put the set of emails in one column with a comma or other delimiter